# jQuery bind('click') produces RangeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

We have a button that, when clicked, would initiate an event as such:

```
buttonElement.click(function (e) {  });
```

When clicked, this button produces a strange error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I have isolated the error to jQuery's `makeArray` method which is trying to pass an array with 310,977 elements to results.push method as shown below:

[image]

I see how that could be a problem as there is bound to be a limit to number of elements that you can try to push onto an array, however my question is why did this error happen in the first place? Traversing up the stack, I find that we stop at a jQuery UI function below:

[image]

Where `this.options.handle` is set to `false` and `this.element` represents one single element. Thus, this would be the same as calling `jQuery(false, '#modalDialog').find('*')`. Not sure what the first parameter does there, but if we are trying to find all children nodes of `#modalDialog`, we would find around 86 nodes and not the 310,977 elements that it somehow finds.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing the error? Should I be doing something differently? FYI, we are using jQuery v1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.6rc6.

Comment: What are the chances that you could upgrade to a version of jQuery that is less than 6 years old?

Comment: what @NathanTaylor, update your jQuery to 1.11 or higher, then come back with a question

Comment: Yeah, @NathanTaylor, I totally agree. That is on the table as a possible solution, but our project is massive and there would be serious testing involved with moving over.

Comment: The chances are, even though it i an old version of jQuery, the problem isn't it.  The problem is more than likely in your own code that is making a call into jQuery.  Much like calling jQuerys AJAX methods with an invalid url returns an error in jQuery when the problem is your own code.  That being said, could you post the code that is calling jQuery?

Comment: Please post relevent code, could be a issue caused by recursion. Inserting 310,977 elements in array shouldn't create problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use event delegation rather than trying to bind events to every single element. With version 1.3.2, you'll need to use .live(). Binding events to individual elements is very taxing.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
$('#modalDialog').live('click', function(e) {});
```

It will be less taxing client side and capture click events that happen inside the #modalDialog element.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I have tried using `live` and I ran into the same error.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with jQuery but rather what is being sent to jQuery. Whatever you are selecting is finding hundreds of thousands of jquery elements. Doing $('#modalDialog') should only grab one element. Unless there are modifications to the jQuery source code being used.